# git: need to build on one branch and merge that branch to another branch

Tags: git

our builds take a long time.  with unit tests about 4 hours.
I am trying to build and run unit tests on master.  At the same time I need to merge master to branch A.

is there a way to NOT change the what the files look like on the file system and to merge to another branch

```
---------\-----master
          \----A
```

something like "git merge from_branch to_branch" or "git merge to_Branch from_Branch"   I have observered some posts with alais but those look like they do a "git checkout A; git merge master" which is not what I want to do.  Can't do checkout because I have processes needing to access files in master

thanks

Comment: Well after merging the files from master would be in A, no? What do you want to be in your workspace? Just be logic you can't have (just) the content of master and (just) the content of a different branch at the same time in any directory. If you need a clean master and the merged content at the same time, you might want to clone the content of the repository to a different place where you merge and access the first workspace from the other processes.

Comment: Branch A has changes beyond master.  What I need it to keep the build going in directory and at the same time appear that I did "git checkout A; git merge master;" problem is if I in 1 window do "git checkout master; mvn clean install", and in another do "git checkout A; git merge master".  if I am in the middle of a build and checkout out a different branch the build as I understand it will grab files from the new branch not the branch it was launched with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Our builds take a long time. with unit tests about 4 hours. I am trying to build and run unit tests on master. At the same time I need to merge master to branch A.

There's a few good practices which will eliminate this problem. First is to not work on `master`, but exclusively on feature branches. `master` should only be used for starting new feature branches and integrating already tested feature branches. This very good practice solves a lot of problems.

```
- B - C - D [master]
           \
            E - F - G [feature]
```

Use `git merge master` to keep your feature branch up to date with changes in `master` (alternatively `git rebase master` to avoid lots of unnecessary merge points). Feature branches can be safely pushed without endangering other branches.

Second is to use a [continuous integration server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration). That is, have a dedicated machine which does nothing but build and run the full test suite on whatever is pushed to the central repository. This has the advantage of providing an environment as close to the real production environment as possible (not whatever happens to be on your development machine). [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) is an example of a CI service, [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) is an Open Source installable CI server.

Note that you can run your own CI server on a virtual machine on your own desktop.

With that in place, you no longer need to wait around for long tests to finish. You can safely push your feature branch and the CI server runs the tests. Meanwhile you can do whatever you want with your development copy.

---

If you don't want to do all that and wish to continue working on `master` and running long tests on a development machine, the simplest solution is to clone *your development copy* to a new location to do your testing.  Cloning your development copy, not the shared remote copy, means it will have your work and branches.

```
git clone /path/to/my/devel /path/to/my/tests
```

Run your tests in `/path/to/my/tests` and do your development work in `/path/to/my/devel`.

Comment: I like the idea of a second clone.  had not thought of that.  We do have a contininious integration server.  the problem is that our developement env is different enough from CI and other servers.   otther develoer unit tests pass on my system but failing on CI.

Comment: @petercooke I cannot encourage you strongly enough to use feature branches and a CI server. It will save you so many future problems.

Comment: we use branches for every jira ticket then merge branches back into master

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @Schwern that the easiest solution for this problem is to have a clone of the repository.

Sometimes instead of a full clone you might find [copied workdir](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/) more convenient. In particular, you don't have to pull/push between these two local git repositories.

The best solution would be a CI server indeed. Intermediary solution on this way could be doing such builds in a docker, provided you can use it and can run your tests on linux.